# Mysterious 401 challenge when using AJAX

Tags: ajax, authentication, asp.net-core, cookies

I have a .NET Core web app hosted on the net.

I'm using claims based auth via cookies:

**When login success...**

```
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(user);
id.AddClaim(new Claim("ViewData", "Allowed"));
id.AddClaim(new Claim("TenantId", user.TenantId));
principal.AddIdentity(id);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```

This all works fine for every user apart from one - however, this one particular user (a 3rd party) is running into an auth popup in their browser (they've tried a few) when they interact with a particular page - every other page works fine.

This leads me to believe the issue is environmental, but I want to understand what could be happening here.

The only difference between the page in question and every other page is that this one does an AJAX post to a controller in order to save some data. The `Home` controller requires auth to view (or edit) the data.

`[Authorize(Policy = "ViewData")]`

The Ajax is your standard stuff

**Razor:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '@Url.Action("_Save", "Home")',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: ko.toJSON(viewModel.model()),
  success: function (result) {
  //... callback code etc
```

Checking the rendered JS shows that the AJAX call is relative to the current page and therefore isn't going to some strange URL

**Raw JS:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Home/_Save',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: ko.toJSON(viewModel.model()), // ... etc
```

I can see the cookie being included in the headers when I look in my browser:

```
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 4775
content-type: application/json
cookie: <cookie details here>
```

Unfortunately, it being a 3rd party I can't really connect to the machine to view the debug console for the browser.

The question I have really is a longshot - it sounds like it could be a proxy issue but I don't understand why making an AJAX call is any different to making the login POST request, unless of course my AJAX setup is missing some auth data that is required - maybe a header of some sort?

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: is your action name correct ? I see that you put _Save here

Comment: Yeah it's correct, it works on 99% of users, just one user on a particular network having the issue.

Comment: so can you call ajax to your controller ?

Comment: All the detail is in the question - I don't think there's any missing information. As stated in the question, it works for every single user across multiple networks apart from one particular user.

Comment: Hmm, maybe some firewall or ip config ?

Comment: Firewall would block communication unless there were some very specific rules that inspected packets and determine what type of HTTP request was being made (which I don't think I've seen any firewall do). Not sure how IP would affect this - why would the site work apart from an AJAX request (to the same host) if there was an IP issue? It sounds more like a  proxy is modifying some part of the HTTP message or request/response chain.

Comment: Is there code in the home/_Save method that can return unauthorized? Did you check the configuration of the user, such as is a claim missing?

Comment: Yes, the `_Save` requires auth but it's the same controller that the `View` page requires (the whole controller requires the same claim and has an `authorize` attribute), so if the user can view the data they can also save the data via the same claim. They aren't having a problem with viewing, just the saving which has left me scratching my head. The only difference between view/save is that view is a GET and save is an XHR post.

Comment: As I understand the AJAX request is made on one of your hosted pages, which when that specific user tries to access it pops up another page? If so, do you know the URL of the pop-up?

Comment: The popup is from the browser (standard credentials dialog) not another site - as if the site has issued a 401 challenge and the browser is asking for basic credentials. It turns out it just started working for them so I suspect it was something network related. All my site does is communicates with itself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen issues somewhat like this, and they have generally been related to security settings.  You might try looking into CSRF headers.  It could be several things.  This could include a local antivirus, on-machine firewall, anti-spyware, or other privacy / protection application.  Since it is a single user, debugging it will be extremely difficult, and I would recommend you figure out how that user's security settings / applications vary from their colleagues'.

Adding your site to the trusted sites list in specific browsers may resolve the single issue.  It's almost certainly something hidden in there.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's a different network per user really (it's a 3rd party supplier portal) so every user is on a different infrastructure. I'm trying to get the 3rd party to send me some details from the debug console, hopefully that will at least show me what's intercepting the request. There's no cross-site calls - it's just an XHR call from the current referrer to another route on the same URL so I'm trying to wrap my head around what would prevent that. It sounds like the request is ending up resolving to another host - the login popup is extra strange...

Comment: Giving you the bounty since I believe this was the issue - just wanted someone else to say the same thing I was thinking, it fixed itself without any changes to the site a week or so later, so I suspect something network related didn't quite trust the site.

Comment: I mean, I appreciate it and I'm sorry nobody came up with a magical spot-on solution. Front-end web development is annoying and hard or anybody could do it well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this sorted itself out after a while - I believe it was probably network related.

The 3rd party tried again a week later and had no issues this time.